# How do I execute some instructions after call refreshcells() from agGrid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

this function is a promise

```
veryfyEdit()

    this.gridApi.stopEditing()
    this.gridApi.refreshCells() as Promise<any>

  }
```

---

i use it here and the return is undefined, but i need know how to make this works whit this grid api

```
openLancarDialog() {

    this.veryfyEdit().then(() => {
      if (this.validadeData()) {
        const dialogRef = this._lancarDialog.open(LancarCdvDialogComponent, {
          width: '50em',
          //height: '40em',
          disableClose: false,
          data: {
            tipoViagem: this.dadosCab.tipoViagem,
            empresaViagem: this.dadosCab.codEmpresa,
            centroCustoViagem: this.dadosCab.area,
            numeroCDV: this.dadosCab.numeroCDV,
            dtoToSave: this.dtoToSave
          }
        });

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {

          if (result != null && result != undefined)
            this.showNotification(result.typeMsg, result.resultMsg)
          if ((result == undefined) || (result.typeMsg === 'success')) {
            this.Accesst('ctrl-despesas-viagens', 'listar-cdv');
          }
        });
      }
    })
  }
```

how do i make this promise works?

Answer (score 0):

Just return the promise you're receiving from `refreshCells` and everything should work fine.

```
veryfyEdit()
  this.gridApi.stopEditing()
  return this.gridApi.refreshCells() as Promise<any>;
}
```

The reason it was not working is because `verifyEdit` was returning `void` on which you were expecting `then`.